# Change formula from excel to vba but got error Expected: )

Tags: excel, vba

I tried to change the formula from excel to VBA
from

```
=WEEKNUM(A1)-WEEKNUM(DATE(YEAR(A1),MONTH(A1),1),1)+1
```

to

```
=Application.WEEKNUM(x)-WEEKNUM(DATE(YEAR(x),MONTH(x),1),1)+1
```

but it's give me an error Expected: )

How to change these formula to work with VBA?
It's use for calculate the weeknum of month

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**Edit:** `Application.WeekNum` also works in this situation.

**Try this:**

```
Dim x As Date

x = Format("7/6/2019", "mm/dd/yyyy")

With Application

MsgBox .WeekNum(x) - .WeekNum(Format(Year(x) & "-" & Month(x) & "-" & 1, "yyyy-mm-dd")) + 1

End With
```

**Demo with date 08/06/2019**

[image]

Comment: Thank you :) It's work for me after I change a bit to Application.WeekNum(x) - Application.WeekNum(Format(Year(x) & "-" & Month(x) & "-" & 1, "yyyy-mm-dd")) + 1

Comment: Ohh Yeah .. I forgot to add `1` .. Anyways .. Glad it worked :) @b478

Comment: Sry again but after I tried for example 08/06/2019(mm/dd/yyyy) and the answer is 10 but it should be 2

Comment: So you are putting x = 08/06/2019 .. Added demo with it. It is giving 2 @b478

Comment: Sorry, that's right but what's about 07/06/2019(mm/dd/yyyy) the answer is 2 but it should be 1

Comment: It is giving 1 in that case. maybe you are not inputting the date in correct format. See the updated answer.

Comment: This answer is misleading. `Application.WeekNum` works fine, there is no need to replace it with `Application.WorksheetFunction`. The problem is that originally the `DATE` is understood as `VBA.Datetime.Date` which is a property that does not accept parameters. It needs to be replaced with `DateSerial`. That alone removes the syntax error, what all you have to do is two prepend `Application.` to the second `WEEKNUM`.

Comment: @GSerg .. Agreed on the `Applicaiton.WeekNum` part,  even i didn't know it will work, so the first thing i did was pointed that out. I can change that. For the rest of the modifications including the `DateSerial` I think the way it is done in the answer should suffice as there can be many ways to deal with a problem like this.

Answer (score 0):

The `DATE` in your original translated formula is understood as `VBA.DateTime.Date`. It is a property and it does not accept parameters. The function that is called [`DATE`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/date-function-e36c0c8c-4104-49da-ab83-82328b832349?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US) in Excel that constructs a date from year, month and day is called [`DateSerial`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/dateserial-function) in VBA. Fortunately, the [`Year`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/year-function) and [`Month`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/month-function) functions are called the same.

So you need to use that instead of the `DATE`, and you need to qualify the second `WEEKNUM` with `Application.` just like you did with the first one:

```vb
= Application.WeekNum(x) - Application.WeekNum(DateSerial(Year(x), Month(x), 1), 1) + 1
```

Comment: There is another issue of the **Input Date Format**. OP mentioned in the comments in my answer, which is causing the wrong results to be displayed, maybe you want to add something for that as well. :)

Comment: @Mikku There is no issue with dates because they are dates as opposed to strings. If `x` is a `DateTime`, this code works like it should. If `x` is a string, then convert it to date first. It is the point where you convert the string where you can have problems. E.g. your `x = Format("7/6/2019", "mm/dd/yyyy")` is in fact this: `x = CDate(Format(CDate("7/6/2019"), "mm/dd/yyyy"))`. It first converts `"7/6/2019"` to a date using the *current system locale* for what is month and what is day, then formats it as `mm/dd`, then parses that to `Date` again *using the current locale*.

Comment: @Mikku So on a computer with a `dd/mm/yyyy` locale, it will first produce the date of `7th of June, 2019`, then format that as `06/07/2019`, then parse it as `dd/mm/yyyy` again, giving `6th of July, 2019`. Amusingly, that *is* what you intended to say in the first place with the original `"7/6/2019"`, but it "works" by accident, not because it is correct.

Comment: It's work correct when I change the format to dd/mm/yyyy before use these formula and Thanks you guys again to care about my question and sorry about my bad english , really appreciate it :)

Comment: I'll make sure to think on those lines when tackling date formatting issues. And I didn't even know about `DateSerial` .... Thanks for the Upload @Gserg ... really appreciate it :)